# Exception Thrown: access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers, reverse

This function reverses the array of pointers and returns it to the main. The main problem is that the code returns an
Exception thrown: read access violation.
fptr was 0xCCCCCCCC.

[image: Minimal Description]

What could be the source of error?

```
int* mirror(int* p[], int n) {
    int* ptr,* fptr;
    int swap;
    ptr = p[0];
    fptr = p[n-1];
    while (fptr > ptr) {
        swap = *ptr;
        *ptr = *fptr;
        *fptr = swap;
        ptr++;
        fptr--;
    }
    return *p;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This code is totally broken. `swap = *ptr;` assigns an integer, not a pointer. `ptr++` increments a wrong pointer (the first element of `p` instead of a pointer to the first element of `p`). No element of the `p` array changes value, ever.

Comment: you shoud replace your argument to be a pointer to pointer to be able to navigate it as you want:
    int* mirror(int** p, int n){

Comment: @user2019716 it won't change a thing, the two definitions are equivalent

Comment: `0xCCCCCCCC` is uninitialized stack memory:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m, yep but he might have seen that p[n-1] != p+n-1

Comment: then he could have defined "int\*\*ptr = p; int\*\*fptr=p+n-1;" and iterate with them instead of incrementing the pointers the table contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
while (fptr > ptr) { ... }
```

`ptr` is the first elements (the first pointer), and `fptr` is the last element (the last pointer), and you are going through the array while the first element is less than the last element, but this imply that the elements in the array are inserted in order of address, which i believe is not..

Instead you should use the dimension (`n`) in order to do that:

```
int** mirror(int* p[], int n) { // return a pointer to integers pointer, not a pointer to integer
    for(int i = 0; i < n/2 ; i++){ // go through the first half of the array
       int* tmp = p[i];  // and those three lines swap the current and the n - current elements
       p[i] = p[n-i-1];
       p[n] = tmp;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the return type `int *` of the function does not make sense.

```
int* mirror(int* p[], int n) {
```

It is better to declare the function as having the return type `void`.

If you have an array of pointers of the type `int *` then a pointer to its elements has the type `int **`.

Moreover the user can pass 0 as the second argument. You should check this case.

The reason of the exception can be the array contains invalid pointers that point outside of the original array.

Also if the array of pointers is formed such a way that it is not necessary that for example the first pointer points to the first element of the original array then you function will not work.

The function can be defined like

```
void mirror( int * p[], size_t n ) 
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( int **first = p, **last = p + n; first < --last; ++first )
        {
            int tmp = **first;
            **first = **last;
            **last = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void mirror( int * p[], size_t n ) 
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( int **first = p, **last = p + n; first < --last; ++first )
        {
            int tmp = **first;
            **first = **last;
            **last = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;
    int a[N] = { 10, 30, 30, 40, 50 };
    int * b[N] = { a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4 };

    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    mirror( b, N );

    for ( const auto &item : a )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 30 30 40 50 
50 40 30 30 10
```

Pay attention to that instead of swapping elements "manually" you could use the standard function `std::swap`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've used the wrong types. The correct version would be:

```
    int **ptr, **fptr;
    int* swap;
    ptr = &p[0];
    fptr = &p[n - 1];
```

With those changes, your function works as expected although what it returns is unusable for most purposes. Either return `p` (`int**`) or make it `void`.

```
void mirror(int* p[], int n) {
    if(n > 0) {                  // check this or you risk undefined behavior
        int** ptr = &p[0];
        int** fptr = &p[n-1];
        int* swap;
        while(ptr < fptr) {
            swap = *ptr;
            *ptr = *fptr;
            *fptr = swap;
            ptr++;
            fptr--;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is already a standard utility for swapping two values called [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap):

```
void mirror(int* p[], int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
        for(int **ptr = &p[0], **fptr = &p[n - 1]; ptr < fptr; ++ptr, --fptr) {
            std::swap(*ptr, *fptr);
        }
    }
}
```

As a last note, there's also a standard utility for reversing the values in a container called [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) which does what your `mirror` function does.

Instead of

```
mirror(arr, std::size(arr));
```

do

```
std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

try navigate your array as follow:

```
void mirror(int* p, int n){
  int* ptr,* fptr;
  int swap;
  ptr = p;
  fptr = p+n-1;
  while (fptr != ptr) {
    swap = *ptr;
    *ptr = *fptr;
    *fptr = swap;
    ptr++;
    fptr--;
  }
}
```

Comment: no, if an element is inserted more than one time, this code  doesn't work

Comment: If he is really manipulating a array of pointers, I don't see why he tries to increment them as they are certainly not contiguous.